# The project currently contains references to more than one version of Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm an Access developer who is learning ASP.NET to build a website with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web. Trying to adapt the VB version of Wingtip Toys demo, starting with a new project and adding forms/code from the demo. It chokes on build, in `IdentityModels.vb` (copied from demo) where it imports `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`, & tries to inherit `IdentityDbContext`.

I get the message:

> The project currently contains references to more than one version of EntityFramework, a direct reference to version 4.4.0.0 and an indirect reference (through 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext') to version 6.0.0.0. Change the direct reference to use version 6.0.0.0 (or higher) of Entity Framework.

How do I change the direct reference (details please - I'm new to VBE for Web)? I did update Entity Framework via NuGet, and according to their notes namespaces > 4.1 should be automatically upgraded. However, according to Windows Explorer the file version of `EntityFramework.dll` I have in the project bin is 4.4.20627.0 (Product version 5); according to NuGet manager I have version 6.1.3 installed.

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution?

Comment: No, just the one I'm trying to build. I do have other projects, including the Wingtip Toys demo, but I don't see them unless I open them as a project.

Comment: Go into NuGet, and Uninstall Entity Framework. Then check and see if you can find any references to it again. If not, try reinstalling, and see if something just got crossed before.

Comment: I'm not seeing an uninstall option for EntityFramework in the Nuget package manager.

Comment: OK, I tried to uninstall using the Package Manager Console, & get this error message:   PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' because 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.0, Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core 2.0.0' depend on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UninstallPackageCommand

Comment: In the NuGet screen, over on the left there are 3 options: "Installed", "Online", and "Upgrades". The Uninstall option is available under the "Installed" option. But yes, oftentimes it will let you know that when you uninstall some packages, it might have to uninstall others that are depended on it. Worst case, you could create a new solution and try again. But upgrade to the latest EF first.

Comment: I get the same message trying that way: it will not uninstall the latest EF because of those dependencies. Is there not any way to change the direct reference to version 4.4 as suggested by the original error message? If I create a new solution, & use code from the demo, at some point it's going to refer to 4.4 again. How would I avoid that?

Comment: I just discovered in Windows explorer search that there are 254 files on my PC called EntityFramework.dll, most of them in the AppData\Local\Application Data\Application Data...(up to 15X)...Application Data\assembly...more numerical subfolders; looks like a new subfolder made every time I used the app; however the Application Data folders are not visible under Local tree. Do I need to uninstall everything (.NET Framework 4.5 & 4.51, ASP.NET MVC 2 & 4, SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012, 2014, Visual Studio Express 2010 & 2013 for Web) & start over? @krillgar

Comment: OK, I just discovered that the Application Data folder is not supposed to show up (see http://www.eightforums.com/performance-maintenance/30484-application-data-folder-inside-application-data-folder.html), so maybe that's not a problem (though a GB hog), no need to panic (yet). It was a surprise to me that there were so many versions of these programs on my computer, however, which may not be healthy. I always figured I would be told to uninstall a previous version if it was incompatible, or else it would be automatically removed. Is any uninstallation advisable here?

Comment: I tried replacing the 4.4 version of EntityFramework in the solution bin with 6.1.3, renaming 4.4 to EntityFrameworkOld. The application now builds without error, but there are still warnings: There was a conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"; plus a couple other similar. System.Net.Http is not in bin, but version 1 is in packages. "View in Browser" gave server error "could not load EntityFrameworkOld". Getting closer, but what now? @krillgar

Comment: OK, so I was not able to repair my solution by reinstalling EntityFramework, but I was able to build a solution free of errors & warnings (so far) that I could view in the browser by following the worst case advice of @krillgar : upgraded EF at the outset of the new project, before adding code from the demo. Thanks krillgar!